# Deactivate menu switching in top bar

Tags: accessibility

Is there a way of turning off the menu switching in the top bar?

For example, when I click on the clock, then move left or right, this switches to the other menus. Another example is the volume control. I find this a little annoying because I often accidentally switch menus when I'm not concentrating on moving the cursor straight down.

It would be ideal if the opened menu would just stay opened until I press somewhere else.

I'm using Ubuntu 13.10 64-bit.

Edit:

Now using Ubuntu 14.04 64-bit, which has not changed anything and I also couldn't find a way of disabling this.